# Disabling data traffic notification "A total of consumption during the lock screen" on LeEco Cool Changer S1

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, notifications, settings, lock-screens, mobile-data

A couple of days ago I received my new phone, a LeEco Cool Changer S1/Coolpad Cool S1. Every time I lock it, I get a notification titled "A total of consumption during the lock screen..". If I open it, it launches the Android settings app and shows me a list of how much data each app has used while the device was locked. I don't really need this and I find it to be quite distracting, I have looked everywhere in the configuration and I could only find options for disabling a daily data limit reminder, which was also set by default, at a measly 30 MB.

I believe this may be something specific to this model in particular, and I could not find any useful information by looking for the exact name of the notification online, which oddly is also one of the few messages that are not translated.

Is there a way to get rid of it?

[image: Android notification]

Comment: Does this notification stay even after you unlock your phone? Like if you pull down the notification bar, do you see that one there?

Comment: @Abochur Yes, actually, the screenshot attached to the post is taken from the notifications bar, after unlocking the phone.

Comment: Oh didn't realize

Answer (score 0):

Here is something you can try:

Long press on the notification, you will then see an icon like this "i" press on it, and you will see a setting for disabling notifications. Set it to 'off' and you will not see it again.

There must be a more direct way of doing this, but I don't have your phone to test it.

Comment: Thanks, I just tried it, but unfortunately, the notifications are sent from the "Android System" application, and the option to block notifications coming from it is greyed out. [Screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/zLmCilT.jpg)